# InertiaJS - Vue - Laravel : Utilizing CSS Files

Tags: css, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I needed to use some global css to remove bootstrap button border on focus through all my vue components

`resources/css/app.css`

```
.btn:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

`resources/views/app.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/app.css"> // 404 Not Found
    @vite('resources/js/app.js')
    @inertiaHead
  </head>
  <body>
    @inertia
  </body>
</html>
```

However, `app.blade.php` doesn't seem to recognize that `app.css` file located in `resources/css`, as it gives me error in console : `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

How to solve that issue ? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Reflecting on your problem

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/app.css">
```

The issue here is that the link you've written in `href` starts looking for the CSS file in the `public` folder instead of the `resources` folder. If you don't want to compile the CSS with Vite and just want to write a plain CSS file, simply place it in `public/css/app.css`. However, this is a rather basic approach. **You can generate much better code with compilation, so I recommend following one of my solutions.**

- [`public` directory](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/structure#the-public-directory) - Laravel Docs

#### Solution # 1

I assume you also want to compile the `app.css` file for the prod version. In this case, you can use the `@vite` Blade directive to load the `app.css` as well.

```
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
```

Also, in the `vite.config.js` file, you need to add the app.css for compilation.

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
 
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel([
            'resources/css/app.css',
            'resources/js/app.js',
        ]),
    ],
});
```

- [Configuring Vite for Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#configuring-vite) - Laravel Docs
- [How to Load Scripts and Styles with Vite](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#loading-your-scripts-and-styles) - Lara

#### Solution # 2 (better for Inertia and another SPA solutions)

In the Laravel documentation for Inertia, another suggested method is to simply import the `app.css` into the `app.js` file in this case.

```
@vite('resources/js/app.js')
```

And let's import the `app.css` into the `app.js` file.

```
import '../css/app.css';
```

- [Configuring Vite for Laravel (from the second code block)](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#configuring-vite) - Laravel Docs